# How to build a bridge between 2 networks?

Tags: debian, networking, bridge, access-point, beagleboneblack

Using Beaglebone.

I have successfully set an AP, but am unable to bridge eth0 and wlan1.

Applications used: hostapd, dnsmasq, bridge-utils

`/etc/dnsmasq.conf`

```
interface=wlan1
dhcp-range=10.10.1.2,10.10.99.254,255.0.0.0,12h
```

`/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf`

```
interface=wlan1
country_code=US
driver=nl80211
ssid=mySSID
hw_mode=g
channel=6
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=password
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK

wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
eapol_key_index_workaround=0
```

`/etc/network/interfaces` **BEFORE** setting bridge

```
auto lo eth0 eth0:1
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet static
  address 192.168.2.99
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  gateway 192.168.2.1
  dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8

iface eth0:1 inet static
  address 192.168.1.226
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  broadcast 192.168.1.255
  network 192.168.1.0
  gateway 192.168.1.1

auto usb0 wlan1
iface usb0 inet static
  address 192.168.7.2
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  network 192.168.7.0
  gateway 192.168.7.2

iface wlan1 inet static
  hostapd /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
  address 10.10.1.1
  network 10.10.1.0
  netmask 255.0.0.0
  broadcast 10.10.1.255
  wireless-power on

#dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
up iptables-restore < /etc/network/iptables.rules
```

`/etc/network/interfaces` **AFTER** setting bridge

```
auto lo eth0
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet manual

auto usb0 wlan1
iface usb0 inet static
  address 192.168.7.2
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  network 192.168.7.0
  gateway 192.168.7.2

iface wlan1 inet manual
  hostapd /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
  wireless-power on

iface br0 inet static
  bridge_ports eth0 wlan1
  address 10.10.1.1
  network 10.10.1.0
  netmask 255.0.0.0
  broadcast 10.10.1.255
  gateway 10.10.1.1

  pre-up iwconfig wlan1 essid mySSID
  bridge_hw xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx #mac address of wireless card

#dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
up iptables-restore < /etc/network/iptables.rules
```

I am able to connect to the network `mySSID`, however I am unable to ping 10.10.1.1, connect to any services running there, or to any other devices. DHCP does not work before and after (small issue that I can try to fix later), and I'm connecting by setting static IP.

This is what is shown when I run the command `sudo iptables --list`

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-request
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:12347
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:12346
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:12345
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:webmin /* Allow connection to webmin */
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

`/etc/network/iptables.rules` file

```
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [123:13390]
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 12347-j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 12346 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 12345-j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 10000 -m comment --comment "Allow connection to webmin" -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j DROP
COMMIT
```

Comment: is `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` set to 1?

Comment: What is your `iptables` ruleset? Does anything work before running `iptables-restore`?

Comment: @ErikF Hi, I have just appended iptables ruleset to the question. Please take a look.

Comment: @NizamMohamed Hi, I have set `/etc/sysctl.conf` to include the statement `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1` and `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` returns `1`.

Comment: Simplify your problem. 1st put aside `DNS` and `iptables`. Make a small network (`/24`) and check it works correctly without killing your ISP and neighbours network. Then check the default route on everyside.

Comment: @danielAzuelos Good advice. It is always sensible to test things in small incremental steps.

Comment: Are you sure you want the networks bridged?  or is having a different subnet on each interface and routing between them (with optional NAT) good enough?

Answer (score 3):

In your network configuration, your `network`, `netmask`,  and `broadcast` configuration do not agree... they are wrong.

```
iface br0 inet static
   bridge_ports eth0 wlan1
   address 10.10.1.1
   network 10.10.1.0     <-------
   netmask 255.0.0.0     <-------
   broadcast 10.10.1.255 <-------
   gateway 10.10.1.1
```

If your network is `10.10.1.0` and the broadcast is `10.10.1.255`, the netmask should be `255.255.255.0`.

As in:

```
iface br0 inet static
   bridge_ports eth0 wlan1
   address 10.10.1.1
   network 10.10.1.0     
   netmask 255.255.255.0     
   broadcast 10.10.1.255 
   gateway 10.10.1.1
```

Here `dhcp-range` in `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` should be:

```
dhcp-range=10.10.1.2,10.10.1.254,255.255.255.0,12h
```

If you really want more devices, and the broader `netmask` was intencional, then it it the `broadcast` that is wrong, and as to correct it:

```
iface br0 inet static
   bridge_ports eth0 wlan1
   address 10.10.1.1
   network 10.10.1.0     
   netmask 255.0.0.0     
   broadcast 10.255.255.255 
   gateway 10.10.1.1
```

Here `dhcp-range` in `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` could be:

```
dhcp-range=10.10.1.2,10.255.255.254,255.0.0.0,12h
```

If you are also using a bridged network, now the interface in dnsmask also changes:

```
interface=br0
```

As for routing to work, besides correcting the netmasks/broadcasts, you also need to tell the kernel to do routing, as, for runtime:

```
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

and to make it active in every reboot, editing `/etc/sysctl.conf` and adding:

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

Beware that some OSes, like iOS, test Internet connectivity as part a health check of (Wifi) connectivity.

Comment: @danielAzuelos indeed....oh my. Added. And the interface too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer... But BB is still not working. I can connect to the network `mySSID`, but am unable to ping 10.10.1.1 or any of the application ports.